# setInterval Spotify apps

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I'm having trouble using setInterval/clearInterval.

I've tried to do something like this: `int = setInterval(someFunction(), 1000);` but it only call `someFunction()` once, instead of once every second?

So I tried to do this: `int = setInterval("someFunction()", 1000);` and it actually works in some way, because it gives me this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: someFunction is not defined` every second?

Why? D:

Comment: The error is in `someFunction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` takes two arguments: a function, and a time in milliseconds for the time between calls.

Your first example is wrong because it doesn't give a function as argument, it *executes* the function and passes the *result* as the first argument. Just change it to `setInterval(someFunction, 1000)` and it'll work.

Comment: Ohh, but I really need to send an argument too D: What can I do then?

Comment: Figured it out :D Just did this: `setInterval(function(){someFunction(true)}, 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
this.interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("tick");
}.bind(this), 100);
```

Comment: Thx, but I would like to use a function made outside of the setInterval